# Rewrite rule for images using .htaccess or nginx config

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

we need to set rewrite rule for some images using **.htaccess** rules or **nginx conf**

---

### Example 1

Request Path:

> https://www.example.com//media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/543x403/db978388cfd007780066eaab38556cef/n/u/number1.png

Response Path:

> https://www.example.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/543x403/n/u/number1.png

---

### Example 2

Request Path :

> https://www.example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/543x403/db978388cfd007780066eaab38556cef/l/e/legal_slide01.jpg

Response Path :

> https://www.example.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/543x403/l/e/legal_slide01.jpg

---

Here the `l/e/` directories are set according to the first two characters of image name here: `legal_slide01.jpg`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
rewrite ^/(media/catalog/product/cache)/\d+/thumbnail/(\d+x\d+)/[a-z0-9]+/(\S+) /pub/$1/$2/$3;
```

[Regex check](https://regex101.com/r/q1Jd4D/1).

Comment: @Knight017 nginx

Comment: I have tested it by converting this rule to .htaccess rule using converter `https://labs.gidix.de/nginx/` , but it is not working.

Comment: Thank you for your refrence, I have managed to create my rule, using your site's refrence.